# Fish shell git_prompt inside TIDE

Tags: fish

Is it possible to force [Fish shell](https://fishshell.com/) extention [TIDE](https://github.com/IlanCosman/tide) to
use [fish_git_prompt](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/fish_git_prompt.html) instead of its own [_tide_item_git.fish](https://github.com/IlanCosman/tide/blob/main/functions/_tide_item_git.fish)?

My goal is to make TIDE git prompt identical to this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@joshuacrass/git-fish-prompt-faa389fff07c).

Right now with default TIDE setting I have this git prompt:

[image]

However, I want to make it look like this, but still use TIDE:

[image]
[Source image](https://medium.com/@joshuacrass/git-fish-prompt-faa389fff07c)

---

fish, version 3.2.1

Fedora 33

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what that tide function does is simply collect the git info and print it. Tide calls it, takes what it prints, and puts it in the correct place. This is also how the fish_git_prompt works - it prints the git stuff, your prompt is responsible for putting that in the correct place.

Simplified:

```
function fish_prompt
    set gitstuff (_tide_item_git)
    # do other tide stuff
    printf '%s' $gitstuff $otherstuff
end
```

When fish calls a function, it goes through $fish_function_path for a file with the name of the function (plus a ".fish" suffix).

So what you would simply do is make your own function `_tide_item_git`, and put it first in $fish_function_path.

I'm not sure how you've installed tide, I'm assuming it's not directly in ~/.config/fish/functions - the normal directory for *your* functions. That's the simple case, so you can just call `funced _tide_item_git`, which will open it in your editor, and replace it with

```
function _tide_item_git
    fish_git_prompt
end
```

then run `funcsave _tide_item_git` once you're happy.

In the more complicated case, make another directory for your functions - `~/.config/fish/myfunctions` maybe - add it to $fish_function_path:

```
set -g fish_function_path ~/.config/fish/myfunctions $fish_function_path
```

(put that in config.fish)

make a file called `_tide_item_git.fish` there and put the above function in.

Comment: This worked:
1. funced _tide_item_git
2. replace it with ...
3. funcsave _tide_item_git
Thank you!